# Gstreamer Is there any video codec that supports alpha channel

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer, codec

I have a raw video data with alpha channel. I want to stream this video data but as you know, raw data streaming is a burden over network.

I couldn't find any video encoder that supports alpha channel. 
I tried openh264enc and vp8enc encoders but alpha is lost while encoding.

Is there any video codec that is on Gstreamer that supports alpha channel ?